# jQuery UI layout on a container div instead of body

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-layout

I'm using jQuery UI layout. I want to apply the layout to a container, not the entire body.

**Works** when I do `$('body').layout();`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/216/

**Fails** when I add a container div and do `$('.myDiv').layout();`.

http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/217/

Am I selecting or applying my container incorrectly?

Comment: Seemed reasonable since this extends / requires jQuery UI. Also, people that work with jquery-ui will have more knowledge of it. Would you say this question has nothing to do with jquery as well?

Comment: http://layout.jquery-dev.net/documentation.cfm#Depends_on - we should tell the author

Comment: ok..my bad...haven't looked at this for years...has been around a long time

Comment: yea, I couldn't find any better panel plugin unfortunately.

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/222/

Comment: yea looks like the div requires "height". Want to post that answer and get some points? ;) I can't do it yet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You container needs to have an explicit size set.
If you add height to your .myDiv it works:

```
<div class="myDiv" style="height:400px">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JPEaa/223/

Answer (score 0):

I also wrap my layout with a `div` element, such as:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
   // layout divs go here
</div>
```

Except that I found it more practical to use the following CSS instead of a fixed height (as Andy has suggested) in order to allow for my layout to properly use the entire browser window and also correctly self adjust as the window was resized.

```
.wrapper {
   position : absolute;
   width    : 100%;
   margin   : 0 auto;
   top      : 0px;
   bottom   : 0px;
}
```

Note that due to the `position: absolute`, this may not be viable for everyone.